# Cyclomatic Complexity is 11 ( max allowed is 10 ) in Java code

Tags: java

I have the following java code that violets the checkstyle saying that "**Cyclomatic Complexity is 11 ( max allowed is 10 )"**

```
 public boolean validate(final BindingResult bindingResult) {
        boolean validate = true;
        for (String channel : getConfiguredChannels()) {
            switch (channel) {
            case "SMS":
                // do nothing
                break;
            case "Email":
                // do nothing
                break;
            case "Facebook":
                // do nothing
                break;
            case "Voice":
                final SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
                if (parser
                        .parseExpression(
                                "!voiceMessageForm.audioForms.?[audioId == '' || audioId == null].isEmpty()")
                        .getValue(this, Boolean.class)) {
                    bindingResult.rejectValue("voiceMessageForm.audioForms",
                            "message.voice.provide.all.audios");
                    validate = false;
                }
                boolean voiceContentErrorSet = false;
                    boolean voiceDescriptionErrorSet = false;
                    for (AudioForm audioForm : (List<AudioForm>) parser
                            .parseExpression(
                                    "voiceMessageForm.audioForms.?[description.length() > 8000]")
                            .getValue(this)) {
                        if (audioForm.getAddAudioBy().equals(
                                AudioForm.AddBy.TTS)
                                && !voiceContentErrorSet) {
                            voiceContentErrorSet = true;
                            bindingResult.rejectValue(
                                    "voiceMessageForm.audioForms",
                                    "message.voice.content.exceed.limit");
                        } else {
                            if (!voiceDescriptionErrorSet) {
                                voiceDescriptionErrorSet = false;
                                bindingResult
                                        .rejectValue(
                                                "voiceMessageForm.audioForms",
                                                "message.describe.voice.content.exceed.limit");
                            }
                        }
                        validate = false;
                    }
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported channel: "
                        + channel);
            }
        }
        return validate;
    }
}
```

Please suggest a suitable way to avoid this checkstyle issue

Comment: So your complexity for this one method is rather high. Well, split up your method in smaller methods. Like do all the audioForm iteration and checking in an extra method and just work with the results of that method. Also consider checking the switch statement. Right now you just have an action for channel "Voice". Either use an if else here, or just extract the whole case block for "Voice" to another method.

Comment: Get a job with a higher cyclomatic complexity limit? Tongue-in-cheek, but forming large & complex productions (as you do) without any intermediate variables makes code difficult to read or debug. Putting it all into one method seems a symptom of the same. Your code is almost OK or quite good.. but damn it needs to be structured better.

Comment: It would be polite to just *look* at your question when you've written it, and fix code formatting and indentation. You are expecting others to help you for free, so least you could do is make it easy and painless for them. Just reformat any code you are pasting to SO first, and make sure it is indented with only spaces. (Or if you don't care about those who might answer the question, then you might care about your SO reputation score... Badly formatted code is unlikely to get upvotes.)

Comment: Hyde, sure , I will keep that in mind while posting the code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd go ahead and extract your code of the "Voice" case to another method. After that your `validate` method will look like:
(You can use the refactoring tools of your IDE to do so.)

```
public boolean validate(final BindingResult bindingResult) {
    boolean validate = true;
    for (String channel : getConfiguredChannels()) {
        switch (channel) {
        case "SMS":
            // do nothing
            break;
        case "Email":
            // do nothing
            break;
        case "Facebook":
            // do nothing
            break;
        case "Voice":
            validate = validateVoice(bindingResult);
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported channel: "
                    + channel);
        }
    }
    return validate;
}
```

**Edit:** (Added extracted method, although I did not really look into it.)

```
private boolean validateVoice(final BindingResult bindingResult) {
    boolean validate = true;
    final SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    if (parser.parseExpression("!voiceMessageForm.audioForms.?[audioId == '' || audioId == null].isEmpty()").getValue(this, Boolean.class)) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("voiceMessageForm.audioForms", "message.voice.provide.all.audios");
        validate = false;
    }
    boolean voiceContentErrorSet = false;
    boolean voiceDescriptionErrorSet = false;
    for (AudioForm audioForm : (List<AudioForm>) parser.parseExpression("voiceMessageForm.audioForms.?[description.length() > 8000]").getValue(this)) {
        if (audioForm.getAddAudioBy().equals(AudioForm.AddBy.TTS) && !voiceContentErrorSet) {
            voiceContentErrorSet = true;
            bindingResult.rejectValue("voiceMessageForm.audioForms", "message.voice.content.exceed.limit");
        } else {
            if (!voiceDescriptionErrorSet) {
                voiceDescriptionErrorSet = false;
                bindingResult.rejectValue("voiceMessageForm.audioForms", "message.describe.voice.content.exceed.limit");
            }
        }
        validate = false;
    }
    return validate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , however can you please show ValidateVoice method ?

Comment: I added it. But I did not check it. (For example voiceDescriptionErrorSet looks suspicious to me, what do you need that bool for?).

Comment: I removed thenvoiceDescriptionerrorSet as correctly identified by you. Thanks now the code runs perfect. Thank you